# Can we use preferences accress multiple different acvtivities in android?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I save preferences in one activities but not able to get saved preferences in other activity. I can access saved preferences in the same activity but not in other one.
It is not giving me any error but always gibing null values in second activity.

> Below is the code:

```
First Activity:
      public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
editor.putString("token", access_token);
 editor.commit();
```

> Second Activity:

```
      public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
   SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);//getPreferences(0); 
     String restoredtoken = prefs.getString("token", null);
     if (restoredtoken== null) {
               ///doing some task;


            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first activity should have:

```
android.content.SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("token", access_token);
editor.commit();
```

Some other suggestions:

- You should use `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`
  instead of the magic number 0 in the
  call to `getSharedPreferences()`.
- In
  your new edit, you show you have two
  different static fields in each
  activity for `PREFS_NAME`. This
  should be a single variable in either
  one, or somewhere else, but should
  not be duplicated.